# How to capture an optional group surrounded by unknown strings?

Tags: regex

I would like to match both strings fully and capture the substring `bbbxxx` as a group with a regular expression. The `xxx` are unknown and variable.

```
aaaxxxbbbxxxddd
aaaxxxddd
```

The closest I came was something like this `(aaa).*?(bbb.*?)?.*` but as soon as I put a `?` behind the group it is not caught anymore.

Here is the real world example: https://regex101.com/r/MAxJix/1
I want to keep the group from the first string but the regex should match `@id="myLabel"` in the second string, too (but not captured into the group).

Thank you!

Comment: If `ddd` is always there then use `^aaa.*?(bbb.*)?ddd$`

Comment: @anubhava this doesn't seem to catch the second string: https://regex101.com/r/wGLwgl/1

Comment: It does match. Make sure to select `m` (MULTILINE) modifier

Comment: Indeed, would you mind looking at my linked example in OP?

Comment: Do you want anything to be captured in the group in 2nd string example?

Comment: No, only what is captured right now: ' oninput= onmouseover='. In the second string the regex should match `@id="myLabel"` but not captured in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with an optional capture group:

```sh
^@(?:id|class)="[^"]*?( on[a-z]*=[^"]*)?"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VlSgY0/3)

**RegEx Explanations:**

- `^`: Start
- `@`: Match a `@`
- `(?:id|class)`: Match `id` or `class`
- `="`: Match `="`
- `[^"]*?`: Match 0 or characters that are not `"` (lazy)
- `( on[a-z]*=[^"]*)?`: Optional capture group that matches space followed by `on<lowercase letters>=` followed by 0 or of any non-`"` characters
- `"`: Match closing `"`

Comment: This works, thank you so much. I spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: is there a way to remove the `$` sign for cases where there is additional text behind the strings? Meaning the additional substrings should be ignored but the results should be like they are right now.

Comment: But then we need to define where should our capture group end? That starts with `on<letters>`

Comment: The next `['"\`]`.

Comment: The regex should only match @(?:id|class) until the second quote sign.

Comment: ok so 2nd line should just match `@id="myLabel"` ?

Comment: In that case use: `^@(?:id|class)="[^"]+?( on[a-z]*=[^"]*)?"`

Answer (score 0):

Will that work for the use case you have?

```
(@id=|@class=).*?( on[a-z]*?=.*)[",',`]|@id=\W\w+\W
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't match `@id="myLabel"` from the second string.